# Multiple Databases Connection on yii2

Tags: php, database, yii2, multiple-databases

I'm trying to use multiple database connection on yii2 framework. Under my db.php file inside the config folder, I have this piece of code:

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'components' => [
        'db1' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=new',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'password',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'db2' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=old',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'password',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
    ],
];
```

In my test.php under the models folder, I have this below...

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\db\Query;

class GetAds extends Model
{
    public function ads()
    {

        $test = Yii::$app->db1->createCommand((new \yii\db\Query)->select('*')->from('members'))->queryAll();

    }
```

when I try to access, I get this error message "Getting unknown property: yii\web\Application::db1"

How do I solve this problem ? I've actually followed this guide [Multiple database connections and Yii 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254540/yii-2-0-multiple-database-connection)

Where have I done wrong ?

The worst thing is, I've set to use just one database... and on my model, I use this code..

```
    namespace app\models;

    use Yii;
    use yii\base\Model;
    use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
    use yii\db\Query;

    class GetAds extends ActiveRecord
    {
        public static function tableName()
        {
            return 'ads_page';
        }

        public static function ads()
        {

            $count=(new \yii\db\Query)->from('ads_page')->count('*'); 
    }
}
```

And I get this error

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
could not find driver
↵
Caused by: PDOException
could not find driver
```

Why is using yii2 so hard ? I've follow all from here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html

please help

Comment: Seems to me this has nothing to do with Yii at all... "could not find driver" seems more like a `PDO` error. Are you sure all relevant php modules are installed? `PDO` alone is not enough, it needs `mysqlnd` as well iirc

Comment: @Blizz, thanks for the tip, I've enable the pdo_mysql under PHP settings using WAMP.... That solves the PDO problem.

Comment: do you merge your db config with other config arrays ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved this problem. This might help others who need this.

Under config/web.php, I added this line "`'db2' => require(__DIR__ . '/db2.php'),`" just under this statement "`'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),`" (without quotes)

and created another new db2.php file under the  config folder using the same codes as in db.php:

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test2',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'password',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

and to call the first database. I use this:

```
$row = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM test")->queryOne();
```

To query table from the second database, I use this:

```
$row = Yii::$app->db2->createCommand("SELECT * FROM test2")->queryOne();
```

Comment: if using multiple db in master/slave mode then checkout the below link
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html

Comment: what if I use ActiveRecord instead of using `Yii::$app::db->createCommand..` for example if I have already used active record methods like `ModelName::find()->all()` in my app, now I want all my clients to use different db for their company. how and where do I tell the application which database to use?

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this:

```
new User(array("db" => Yii::$app->db1));
```

or do this:

```
User::find()->where(...)->all(Yii::$app->db2);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have the `php_mysql` and `php_pdo_mysql` extensions
   installed.
2. The `\yii\db\ActiveRecord` class should know what database it's working with

This is the code to you add to the model to make it aware of its database.

```
public static function getDb()
{
    return Yii::$app->get('db1');
}
```

Comment: what if I use ActiveRecord instead of using Yii::$app::db->createCommand.. for example if I have already used active record methods like ModelName::find()->all() in my app, now I want all my clients to use different db for their company. how and where do I tell the application which database to use? Does ActiveRecord classed always make a call to this function `getDb()`