# Auto complete for signup form in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii-components

Good day!!

I need autocomplete in yii2 in one text input. I have two database and I need to connect to the second database to get the value on the table of that database.

Can someone please show me how.. Just use an example. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Databases Connection on yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453870/multiple-databases-connection-on-yii2)

Comment: @Sfili_81 no, it's not.

Comment: OK so can you explain better what you want? Show us what you have tried? What type of error you get?