# Yii 2.0 : 2 database connection

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I read this question [yii 2.0 multiple database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254540/yii-2-0-multiple-database-connection?answertab=active#tab-top), and use the answer of @Ali MasudianPour.

I follow the first step:

> First you need to configure your databases like below:

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'db1' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database1',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'db2' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database2',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
    ],
]; ?>
```

But in my configuration in my `db` it gives me this error:

> The configuration for the "db" component must contain a "class"
>   element.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `db` component is main and required and you simply omitted its declaration.

Rename `db1` and `db2` for example to `db` and `db1` accordingly:

```
return [
    'components' => [
        // Main connection
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database1',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        // Another connection
        'db1' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database2',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
    ],
]; ?>
```

**Update:**

Note that for the basic application `db` is configured in separate file `config/db.php` and then required in main config `config/web.php` like so:

```
'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
```

So you can configure main connection in `db.php` and add additional below as `db1`.

Comment: it gives the same result. `The configuration for the "db" component must contain a "class" element.`

Comment: It can't be the same, as you can see in changed config, `class` is included in `db ` component configuration. I recommend you to check if it's overrided in other application or local config files.

Comment: how can I know if it's override in other application  or local config files? can you give me example ?

Comment: What application you are using? Basic or advanced?

Comment: My application I  use: Basic

Comment: Seems like it's not the reason in this case. Check that you renamed it properly again.

Comment: i just copied your answer and change the database name, i think there's no problem with that. i tried to use my old config. but it's just for 1 database , the syntax is like this:
` return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database1,
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];`

it works when i used like that , i don't know why it's not reading the `class` inside component and db.

Comment: Updated answer with some explanation for basic application.

Comment: it has error `Setting read-only property: yii\web\Application::db`

Comment: Who downvoted? This should be the right answer. +1. Btw I think that for `db` the `class` property can be ommitted?

Comment: It can. "db" is by default assumed to be a `\yii\db\Connection`

Comment: @Blizz i just add `'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),` in main config `config/web.php` like you said, and tried to run the code, but still got this error : **The configuration for the "db" component must contain a "class" element.**

Comment: I also using Basic template, and tried following this answer, but I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 3):

Simply you just have to create separate file for each database .

1. `config/db` ->

   ```
   'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
   'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database1',
   'username' => 'root',
   'password' => '',
   'charset' => 'utf8',
   ```

   To access another db create file in **config** named `db1.php` add add another db configuration.
2. `config/db1` ->

   ```
   'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
   'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database2',
   'username' => 'root',
   'password' => '',
   'charset' => 'utf8',
   ```
3. In  `config->web.php` add

   ```
   'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
   'db1' => require(__DIR__ . '/db1.php'),
   ```
4. To access the Model:

   ```
   public static function getDb() {
        return Yii::$app->db1;
   }
   ```

Comment: I've tried this one in Basic template, but why it only read the 'db', not both of them? thanks