# Yii2 Db Connection to another server

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to connect a db from another server.
Is it possible to connect Yii2 db connection from one server to another server db?

Comment: Yep, very possible.

Comment: even possible to connect multiple database check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254540/multiple-database-connections-and-yii-2-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In db config you have to specify IP address of your database in your `dsn`:

```
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=YOUR_IP_HERE;dbname=YOUR_DB_HERE',
```

And that's all.

It's possible that second server doesn't allow connections on `3306` port, so you have to allow it in `iptables` (linux servers).

Comment: when i specified the ip address and db nameith shows this error "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

Comment: Are you sure that your second server database allows remote connections?

Comment: I am giving my server IP, but its taking the IP of the current local-machine. 
Error Displayed : 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.94.196' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible, even you can connect yii2 application with many different database server. You just need to add a bit in the configuration file as below:

```
    'components' => [

    'db_server1' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=DB_NAME;port=PORT_CONNECTION',
        'username' => 'DB_USERNAME',
        'password' => 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],

    'db_server2' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=OTHER_HOST;dbname=DB_NAME;port=PORT_CONNECTION',
        'username' => 'DB_USERNAME',
        'password' => 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],];
```

Hope can help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure another db connection in your web.php inside the config folder:

```
    'db2'=>[
        'class'=>'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8'            
    ],
```

and then you call db2 component.