# independent db for an module

Tags: php, yii

Hello Yii developers :)

Im new in yii freamwork, I want to have a independent database for my module, so I create a db config in my module like this:

1-first I create db.php file that return db config

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Rezvania
 * Date: 3/10/2018
 * Time: 11:31 AM
 */
return[
    'class'=>'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn'=>'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_entry_mdu',
    'username'=>'root',
    'password'=>'',
    'charset'=>'utf8',
    'tablePrefix'=>'tbl_entry_mdu_'
];
```

2-so i create config file that modify my module configs

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Rezvania
 * Date: 3/10/2018
 * Time: 11:30 AM
 */
$db=require __DIR__.'/db.php';
return[

    'defaultRoute'=>'entry',
  'components'=>[
      'db'=>$db,
  ]

];
```

3-finaly I set that in my Module class

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Rezvania
 * Date: 3/10/2018
 * Time: 11:26 AM
 */

namespace app\modules\entry;
use yii\base\Module;
use yii;
class EntryModule extends Module
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
        \Yii::configure($this,require __DIR__.'/config/config.php');

    }
}
```

now when I try to use of tables data I get this error:

> The table does not exist: `tbl_entry_mdu_user`

Comment: So check your database, do you really have `tbl_entry_mdu_user` there?

Comment: yes, I'm sure that i have this table, but now my main question is that can i have a independent db for my modules in Yii? or Not!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple database connections and Yii 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254540/multiple-database-connections-and-yii-2-0)

Comment: thanks, Now i know that i can have multiple databases, but my problem staying yet.